# mod_rewrite and double slash issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, configuration

I applied the following `mod_rewrite` rule in `Apache2` to redirect from non-www to www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, there's a double slash issue:

- When I go to `http://www.example.com` it
  correctly rewrites the URL to
  `http://www.example.com/`
- When I go to
  `http://www.example.com/somepage`, it correctly
  rewrites the URL to
  `http://www.example.com/somepage`
- **If I
  go to `http://example.com`, it
  rewrites the URL to
  `http://www.example.com//`** (double final slash)
- If I go to
  `http://example.com/somepage`, it
  correctly rewrites it to
  `http://www.example.com/somepage`

Is my configuration good for SEO?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

because `$1` by default contains the index path `/`

Comment: It's worth clarifying for other readers that this only applies when the directive is used in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context. When used in a _directory_ (ie. `<Directory>` container) or `.htaccess` context then the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ does NOT contain a slash prefix.

Comment: @MrWhite That is a huge distinction which answered my problem. I had moved all my `.htaccess` directives to the `.conf` and nothing worked. It was the leading `/` issue! Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

```
RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: IMHO this solution should be preferred in relation to the accepted one, since leaving out the leading / from the match is cleaner than leaving out from the rewrite.

Comment: Minor point, but there is no need to backslash escape the forward slash in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_.

Comment: @MrWhite why there is no need to escape it? Isn't it a special character? Thanks!

Comment: @StockBreak The forward slash is not a "special character" in regex. The forward slash is sometimes used to "delimit" regex (in some environments), but in Apache config files (except when using Apache expressions), the _spaces_ are the regex (and argument) delimiters.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that Apache used `/` as a delimiter internally.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you will always have double slashes due to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

combined with the fact that REQUEST_URI (that you are matching on) normally contains a starting slash. What you can try is `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1`, and then send a broken HTTP request `GET foo HTTP/1.0` and see if Apache deals with it properly.

Answer (score 3):

Putting a slash into your pattern should resolve this issue:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the root path is `/`, and you are appending whatever you get in `RewriteRule` (the first case works fine because it *doesn't* match the condition so no rewrite is performed).

You can try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
# for the home page
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
# for the rest of pages
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```