# Spurious, but frequent double slashes in path after Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A client wants to strengthen his main brand and consolidated the content of the various domains used for the respective sub-brands in subdirectories under the hood of his main domain (brand):

```
www.example.com
                |_ .htaccess
                |_  brand1
                          |_ files
                          |_ includes/header.inc
                          |_ scripts/functions.php
                |_  brand2
                |_  brand3
```

All hitherto separate domains now point at `www.example.com`, in `.htaccess` in root requests are rewritten to the resp. subdirectories (some domains are treated individually as domain/brand do not translate one to one, but the pattern is the same):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www.)?(brand1|brand2|brand3)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^               https://www.example.com/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

These directives are followed by a `RewriteBase /` directive and some rules treating incomplete file (not directory) names and passing images to a script for watermarking.

Generally this works fine.  However, there are spurious, but too frequent to ignore, errors in Apache (2.4) & PHP (7.2) error logs whence PHP `include` can't find the file or the watermark script can't load the image file.

Comparing these with the access log it turns out that in these cases requests came with a double slash:

```
"GET /brand1//path/to/file HTTP/1.1"
            ^^
```

where `path/to/file` represents the root-based URI of respective former separate domain.

Most if not all of such requests come from search bots (Google, Yandex, Bing/MSN). Yet these same bots issue correct requests as well, nor can I replicate the double slash occurences in the browser for the very same files, with neither old (rewritten) nor new (current) URLs.

Obviously this can be remediated by `RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]` (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4278042 et al), but I rather would crush the error at its root if possible.

Thanks for any insight/suggestion/help.

**EDIT:**

In the case of above `GET /brand1//path/to/file HTTP/1.1` Apache access log states return codes of either 200 or 500 (could not see a pattern) and 404 if the file is indeed missing. Intentionally entering an URL with double slashes in the browser displays the page up to the point of some `include`.

For `<?php include 'includes/header.inc' ?>;` the PHP error log says

```
PHP Warning:  include(/home/http/htdocs/example/brand1/path/to/file/brand1/path/to/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mnt/webnnn/htdocs/example/brand1/path/to/header.inc on line XX
```

`/home/http/htdocs/example/brand1/path/to/file` includes `header.inc` (so far it works; relative path) which in turn includes `str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/brand1/path/to/functions.php'`.

(The hosting server returns a wrong path in $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], therefore the `str_replace(...)`, which works fine unless that double slash occurs, breaking the match. So far I have tracked this down.)

Images passed in `.htaccess` to watermarking script `brand1/watermark.class.php` raise

```
PHP Warning:  exif_imagetype(/path/to/image.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mnt/webnnn/htdocs/example/brand1/watermark.class.php on line XX
```

with the leading slash coinciding with the double slash in the Apache log (w/o these it correctly is `imagecreatefromjpeg(path/to/image.jpg)`).

Meanwhile I revised error handling in `watermark.class.php`, no longer relying on the `-s` flag and other conditions in `.htaccess`. Rewriting double-slashed URLs works, too, but still I have no idea from where these origin in the first place.

Comment: Could you add some of the errors you are getting - one will do if they are all of the same type but otherwise a selection might be helpful.

Comment: @Bananaapple Please see my edit above. Thanks.